# How to equally space out dynamic number of components

Tags: extjs

I have a container with a hbox layout that can have x number of components inside it. I want the components to be equally spaced apart along the whole horizontal length. I can't use flex because the components themselves need to have fixed width. How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use column width instead .

Comment: So you want (numbers made up) 12 components of 200 px each spaced equally into a component of width 250px?

Comment: @Alexander so say the container has a width of 1000 px, and each component has a width of 20 px. I want to space them equally into the container but the number of components will vary, so one time it could be 5 components spaced equally and the next time 10 components spaced equally. I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: You could put a flexing `tbspacer` between every adjacent pair of components, would that solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with spacers or with a component itself, here's the code to handle it:

```
console.clear();

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
            return color;
        }

        var container = Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            fbar: {
                items: {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'add component',
                    listeners: {
                        click: function (btn) {
                            var newCont = Ext.create({
                                xtype: 'container',
                                width: 10,
                                style: 'background-color:' + getRandomColor() + ';'
                            }),
                            masterContainerContentLenght=container.items.length,
                            getNewSpacer=function(){
                                return Ext.create({
                                    xtype:'component',
                                    flex:1
                                });
                            };

                            if(masterContainerContentLenght===0){
                                container.add(getNewSpacer());
                                container.add(newCont);
                                container.add(getNewSpacer());
                            }else{
                                container.insert(container.lastAddedIndex,newCont);
                                container.insert(container.lastAddedIndex+1,getNewSpacer());
                            }

                            container.lastAddedIndex=container.items.items.indexOf(newCont);
                            console.log(container.lastAddedIndex);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        container.show();
    }
});
```

You can show [a working fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bv3)